# clickable button over clickable image

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to have a card with clickable main image content and clickable button over it. See the image

[image].

The image has one onclick action, button second one. But I am unable to fire action from the button, it always does an action associated with the image click.

My code is:

```
<v-card flat class="rounded-0">
    <v-img style="z-index: 0" :src="product.images" 
        v-on:click="action1">
        <v-card-title class="align-end fill-height" primary-title>

            <v-btn class="blue" style="z-index: 9999" v-on:click="action2">clickable</v-btn>
           </v-card-title>

          </v-img>                       
 </v-card>
```

Is there something I am missing out?

Comment: you syntax seems to be incorrect: `<v-img style="z-index: 0" :src="product.images" v-on="on"
        v-on:click="logclick(product, 'product_exit'); track_result_click()">`

Comment: Simon, which part do you actually mean? I tried to clean it up, but still do not see where is the error in the code.

Comment: `v-on="on"` and `v-on:click="...` together

Comment: in the answer the code has been corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in above code, you have two events one is parent and another one is child

Once the parent is clicked only parent function is invoked. If you click on child, it fires child first then parent function

To stop the parent trigger when child is clicked use stop modifier

The below code will work as expected

```
<v-card flat class="rounded-0">
    <v-img style="z-index: 0" :src="product.images" v-on:click="action1">
        <v-card-title class="align-end fill-height" primary-title>
            <v-btn class="blue" style="z-index: 9999" v-on:click.stop="action2">clickable</v-btn>
        </v-card-title>
    </v-img>                       
</v-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent bubbling you need a modifier on your click event called `self`:

```
v-on:click.self="action1"
v-on:click.self.stop="action2"
```